# Could not find main class when double clicking jar- tried quite a few solutions

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, build

I searched through other posts related to this problem but haven't been able to find a solution that fixes my problem.

I can use java -jar helloworld.jar via command prompt and it runs perfectly, however if I double click on it command prompt briefly opens and I glimpse the error in the title.

One person offered a solution in the form of going into the registry and checking HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\Shell\Open\Command value is set properly to javaw file pathway, which it as:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*

Another solution offered reference to having in PATH Environment Variable, I have this in there:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

I am certain the MANIFEST file is correct, as the project runs fine in Netbeans and of course when you try Command Prompt java -jar helloworld.jar it works perfectly.

Can anyone advise?  I have been fiddling with this for hours to no avail and I can't determine where I am going wrong.  Thanks stackoverflow!

EDIT:

I have also tried:

> assoc .jar

and

> ftype jarfile

which return
.jar=jarfile
and 
jarfile="C:\Program FIles\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*

respectively.

here is the manifest information:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2 Created-By:
>   1.8.0_05-b13 (Oracle Corporation) Class-Path:  X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build Main-Class: mypackage.HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, while exporting Jar it asks for Main class. There you have to select a Main class from multiple classes.

From command line -

```
java -cp name.jar classname
```

here the classname should be a fully qualified class name.

Comment: Hi sorry I should have added a NETBEANS tag, I have the main class set correctly and have checked the manifest file to confirm it.  The java file runs perfectly if you do it through command prompt java -jar helloworld.java but not if you double click it!  I know it's something to do with my file association but I am 99% sure it's set correctly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your JAR file works fine.

If you want to see the return values when executing the program, it is better to redirect the input and output to a small Swing Window. Or you would make the console wait for some input.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a problem a while ago (running IPConfig) where the command would run and the command prompt would close before I could see anything. It sounds like this is what's happening here, as far as the window going away before you can see the error.

Try opening command prompt first and running the file without the "java -jar" command and switch. As I understand things, double-clicking the .jar will try exactly that (running the file without the java command), error out, and close the command prompt window. Maybe trying this will keep the command prompt open and allow you to see the error message. It may also describe the problem (double-clicking doesn't use the "java -jar" command as far as I know).